# Authenticate wss 3.0 site programmatically

Tags: wss-3.0, asp.net

I have an asp.net app which has a hyperlink to a wss site, both sites are in same machine and same iis. When a user clicks that link he is prompted for windows authentication by iis for accessing the wss site. My requirement is to bypass this prompt and pass my credentials from asp.net and move into the wss site through Response.Redirect() method.

Let me know 
-RHM

Answer (score 1):

Windows Authentication in SharePoint is actually NTLM (NT Challenge) which would lead to the double-hop issue as the 2nd authentication cannot be performed due to credentials being hashed the 1st time, so unless you enable Kerberos on both SharePoint and ASP.NET (which will by default solve your issues) you would be left with either implementing Claims-Based and perform programmatic authentication (not really easy) e.g using Authentication.asmx and keep the session - really messy.

You could also rely on ISA/ForeFront to perform of this for you provided you can have it.